# Syntax errors when trying to write MySQL trigger to substitute CHECK constraint on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, constraints

I'm trying to make a MySQL trigger that would act as a CHECK constraint since it is not supported in the version of MySQL I am using.

Basically I am doing a database for a library, where table bookloan is a record of all loans that have ever been made.

bookloan has 4 columns:
- `borrowerNo`: Id of the borrower
- `copyNo`: Id of the book that was rented
- `dateOut`: Date the book was rented
- `dateDue`: Date the book is due, always 14 days after dateOut

I am trying to make a restriction where a borrower can't rent more than 3 books at the same time. Here's my code for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maxbooks 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON bookloan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF COUNT(SELECT * FROM bookloan WHERE borrowerNo = NEW.borrowerNo AND dateOut <= NEW.dateOut AND dateDue > NEW.dateOut) >= 3 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Maximum number of book rentals has been reached';
END IF;
END;
```

Here's the error message I am getting from MySQL:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF COUNT(SELECT * FROM bookloan WHERE borrowerNo =
>   NEW.borrowerNo AND dateOut <=' at line 4

I'm guessing the error is from the `Count()` function, but do not know how I could format it so that I get the information that I want.

Thanks!

Comment: try using `count(*)` instead of count on query. count is an exaggerate function and can work with SQL syntax only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `count(*)` instead of using it on query results returned. Just like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maxbooks 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON bookloan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookloan WHERE borrowerNo = NEW.borrowerNo AND dateOut <= 
NEW.dateOut AND dateDue > NEW.dateOut) >= 3 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Maximum number of book rentals has been reached';
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I still get a syntax error with that code unfortunately, but thanks for answering.

Comment: @acroteau what is the new error? This code appears to be correct, where your original code does not.

Comment: With an exact copy-paste of the code, I'm getting this: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR UPDATE
ON bookloan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookloan WHE' at line 2